# multi file upload via form api drupal6

Tags: drupal, file, forms, file-upload

hey, im trying to do a multi file upload on my form, i used form api for that and drupal_render , but i cant find where i can do $form['uploadfield']=array(...multi files amount=3)

anyone has code to implment multi file upload in form api on d6?

Answer (score 1):

Currently I do not think this is possible through the FAPI. See the discussions below:
http://drupal.org/node/452446

http://drupal.org/node/625958

There are some other options however. You can try using a Drupal module that implements this such as [SWFUpload](http://drupal.org/project/swfupload) or [Image FUpload](http://drupal.org/project/image_fupload) (if you want to upload images).

SWFUpload can be used with [CCK's Filefield](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) and Image FUpload can be used with [CCK's imagefield](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield)

**EDIT:** If your form is used for a custom content type, these articles/discussions should be helpful to you:
http://drupal.org/node/722268
http://drupal.org/node/702156
http://www.openbandlabs.com/blog/2009/06/programmatic-cck-content-type-creation

Using these methods, people have been able to add a CCK FileField to their custom content type.